# Dynamic authorised redirect URIs in google oauth

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I have this dynamic URI need to sign in with google. For example:

```
http://mypage.com/login/google/username1
http://mypage.com/login/google/username2
http://mypage.com/login/google/username3
http://mypage.com/login/google/username4
```

How I can make `username1 - username4` as a **variables?**

For your references:

[image]

Comment: The session is still active right? Store the username in the season, redirect to some generic `http://mypage.com/login/google/continue` which will redirect based on the session variable

Comment: I have done it. Thanks.